# How to sort by a propery of ManyToMany Object in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter an object by the "order" property of a ManyToMany object. the tricky part here is that i'm trying to exclude a specific unit from the query but cannot seem to find how to do it.

So, what basicaly the query should do is:

1. get all Question objects assigned to a specific unit(one of the Unit's in M2M Field)
2. sort them by the "order" property of all the other Unit's that are assigned to the Question

Example

```
ID  Question     Question.unit
1   question1    unit1, unit2
2   question2    unit1, unit3
3   question3    unit1, unit4
```

```
ID  Unit     Unit.order
1   unit1    1
2   unit2    2
3   unit3    3
4   unit4    4
```

Code:

```
#views - my code so far, seems to filter by all units
def get_questions_beside_unit():
    questions = Question.objects.filter(unit=quiz.unit).order_by('unit__order')

#models
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    unit = models.ManyToManyField(Unit)

class Unit(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `exclude()`?

Comment: I think the my problem is that i'm trying to sort it by a specific "Unit" order. In my example - not "unit1" but the other on in every "Question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Prefetch, that way you can control what related objects get fetched from the DB.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

pf = Prefetch('unit', Unit.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4]))
questions = Question.objects.prefetch_related(pf).order_by('unit__order')
```

During the sort, there are only Units conforming to the Prefetch filter, so you should get the result you want. In my example, it only uses Units with id in [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Interesting, I'll Try that :)